# Azure bot using Luis staging version

Tags: azure, bots, azure-language-understanding

I want to use staging version in the my bot. My bot only use the Production version from Luis. How can I change it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the version, open your app by selecting its name on `My Apps` page, and then select `Manage` in the top bar, then select `Versions` in the left navigation.

The list of versions show which versions are published, where they are published, and which version is currently active. You could select a version from the list, then select `Make Active`.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions#set-active-version).